# How display multi-page license and accept from shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, sh, solaris, aix

I would like to write a shell script which should display multi-page license and should prompt the user for accepting the license. I am not able to find the proper solution that will work on Linux, Solaris, AIX and HP-UX.

Thought of using less or more command to display, but not sure how to accept the user input in between. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with `${PAGER:-less} "$file"; echo "Do you accept this license?"; read accepted`?

Comment: @TobySpeight. Thank you. But I have to press multiple space for each page and q to come out of 'less' and then finally user can enter 'y/n'. what if I dont want to go through all the page. User can  just say 'y' to accept the license in the first page of license itself

Comment: Can we assume you don't have `whiptail` or `dialog` installed on these machinse?

Comment: correct. All our machines are customers environment where most of the util or software's are not installed by default

Comment: Also, you don't need `q` to exit `less --quit-at-eof`; you might also be able to make use of a suitable `lesskey` file to exit on `n` or `y`.

Comment: Why not just avoid the theater of having the user accept the license from inside the shell script?

Comment: @TobySpeight I will try that if there is no other option. Thank you

Comment: @chepner Please let me know if you any other suggestions?

Comment: If this is for a software installer, I believe that Solaris and HP-UX provide means to display a EULA as part of their package tools.  I'd be surprised if AIX didn't also provide something; it's a bit longer since I've target that platform.  On Debian-like Linux distributions, it's usual to use a Debconf question to display such messages (that will adapt to available terminal capabilities, using `whiptail`, `dialog`, `readline` etc as appropriate/configured.  I don't know about RPM-based Linux distributions.

Comment: thanks @TobySpeight. I am going with your 'less --quit-at-eof' suggestion. That suits me well. Thanks again